# Uploading artifacts error using GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, artifact

I am trying to run 'mvn package war:war' command using GitLab CI.  I have run the following yaml script: [please ignore identation]

```
stages:
 - package
job1:
 stage: package
 script:
   - mvn package war:war
 artifacts:
  paths:
   - target/*.war
```

This script resulted in following error:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijORG.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NZrX.jpg)

I think it is because of proxy but not sure. Though I found similar blogs I didn't find exact solution. Please someone help me out.

Thanks in advance!!!